# Bootstrap Table Row Click Overriding Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

I've looked up how to stop the row click on a bootstrap table plugin to stop firing, but the one method I can find doesn't seem to be working, but it does for other people so I assume something else is wrong somewhere.

First I add my button to the table:

```
// Show the edit button on users table
settings.editFormatter = function (value) {
    return "<button id='user-edit' class='btn user-edit text-center' data-userId='" + value + "'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o' aria-hidden='true'></i> Edit</button>";
}
```

Then I've created a function to handle the button click:

```
// Open Edit modal
settings.editUser = function () {
    var userEditModal = $("#userEditModal");
    $("#user-edit").on("click", function(event) {
        userEditModal.modal();
        event.stopPropagation(); 
    });
}
```

And finally I call that function when the table is created:

```
settings.editUser();
```

Comment: Have you tried event.stopImmediatePropagation() see https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/

Comment: I have yeah - that doesn't work either

Comment: Can you provide fiddle that not working.

Comment: Not without the table data I can't no

Comment: It's not a z-index problem ? button would be below table ?

Comment: Maybe the row click event is handled before your custom click event, and then event.stopPropagation() have no impact on it.

Comment: @BelowtheRadar - if that's the case, is there any way for me to get round that?

Comment: You can first test if thats true by printing a message in the console for both events. If that's the case, then you can remove the row click event, or insert your custom click event in it

Comment: Looks like the button click doesn't run at all - but to be fair that doesn't make sense either

Comment: Are you sure editUser() is called after the button html is added to the DOM?

Comment: When I debug the code it's definitely run

Comment: I think you will have to reproduce in a JSFidlle